# Save file to location?

Tags: c#, file

I am downloading a file off a website and it always saves into my Download files, is there a way where i can select where to save the file to?

```
public void myDownloadfile(string token, string fileid, string platform)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    parameters.Add("Token", token);
    parameters.Add("fileid", fileid);
    parameters.Add("plateform", platform);

    string url;
    url = "https://formbase.formmobi.com/dvuapi/downloadfile.aspx?" + "token=" + token + "&fileid=" + fileid + "&platform=" + platform;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
}
```

Comment: You need to bring up the "file save as" dialog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` just opens your default web browsers on the required url.
You can set your browser to open save as dialog.

But better use `WebClient.DownloadFile`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx
It receives the path of the target file as one of it's parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are downloading the file using your system's standard browser, you have to change the setting there.

---

Otherwise, you probably want to use the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class to download a file, since it is as easy to use as

```
using System.Net;

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("http://mysite.com/myfile.txt", @"c:\myfile.txt");
```

(example from [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/download-files/))

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Process.Start that will launch the default browser to download the file and the download location will be very dependent on the users system settings. Use WebClient to download it instead and it will be easier to specify a location.

```
    public void myDownloadfile(string token, string fileid, string platform)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters.Add("Token", token);
        parameters.Add("fileid", fileid);
        parameters.Add("plateform", platform);

        string url;
        url = "https://formbase.formmobi.com/dvuapi/downloadfile.aspx?" + "token=" + token + "&fileid=" + fileid + "&platform=" + platform;
        System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient()
        wc.DownloadFile(url, "C:\\myFile.ext")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebClient to download the data and use  SaveFile Dialog to set the default location where you which to start.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/download-files-over-the-web-with-nets-webclient-class/695

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpResponse`.

Go through the link: [prompt a save dialog box to download a file](http://corymathews.com/aspnetc-prompt-a-save-dialog-box-to-download-a-file/)